# Are market prices listed by exchanges weighted by transaction size?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, exchange-rate, market, price-discovery

Suppose I buy 0.0001 BTC for $1.23 on some hypothetical exchange. Does that mean that the market price on that exchange at that time is $12,300?  The reason I ask is that there is a huge difference between the willingness of buyers to pay inflated prices for miniscule fractional amounts of BTC and the willingness of buyers to pay $10,000 or $15,000 for a "whole" bitcoin.

Do exchanges, as a rule, weight their calculation of market price by the size of the transaction, or do transactions involving fractional units of BTC count the same as large transactions involving whole units of BTC?